# Filtering a dataframe with the values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a bit of a complicated selecting in two dataframes.

Say I have a dataframe like this

```
       country         pop continent  lifeExp    gdpPercap
0  Afghanistan  31889923.0      Asia   43.828   974.580338
1      Albania   3600523.0    Europe   76.423  5937.029526
2      Algeria  33333216.0    Africa   72.301  6223.367465
```

(Actually this dataframe is product of a previous filtering I did)

And I have another dataframe like this

```
country         year         Production
Afghanistan    1980          20
Afghanistan    1981          10
Afghanistan    1983          5
Albania        1970         30
Albania        1980         40
Abisinia       1990          3
Algeria        1990         30
Angola          1980         2
Angola         1982         30
```

So what I want to get is the second dataframe but filtered with only the countries present in the first dataframe..(Afghanistan, Albania and Algeria)

What would be the best pythonic way to get this (hopefully in a fast operation)?

Comment: `df2[df2['country'].isin(df1['Country'].unique())]`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) :

```
out= df2.loc[df2["country"].isin(df1["country"])]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

       country  year  Production
0  Afghanistan  1980          20
1  Afghanistan  1981          10
2  Afghanistan  1983           5
3      Albania  1970          30
4      Albania  1980          40
6      Algeria  1990          30
```